# Using ajax to update a label based on two different dropdowns

Tags: javascript, ajax

So my issue is this-

I have a page with two dropdowns and a label. I have it set up so that the two dropdowns are cascading, which is working fine, however what I would like to do now is set the text of the label to a value that is determined by the two drop downs.

Right now I have it set so when the second dropdown is changed, it will make a call to the server which determines the value for the label. The issue I am facing is that I do not know how to grab the value of the first drop down inside of the second drop downs on change function-- am i missing something really simple maybe? I have tried using ("#elementID").val() but i get the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'val'"

Code below- any help is SUPER appreciated!

```
$(function () {
var cascadingDropDownRelease = new CascadingDropDownAssociation();

//binding change event of the "make" select HTML control
// the cascading drop downs are working as expected
$('#make').on('change', function () {
    var selectedArea = $(this).val();

    //if selected other than default option, make a AJAX call to server
    if (selectedArea !== "-1") {
        $.post('/Association/GetFullContainers',
            { selectedArea: selectedArea },
            function (data) {
                cascadingDropDownRelease.resetCascadingDropDowns();
                cascadingDropDownRelease.getContainerSuccess(data);
            });
    }
    else {
        //reset the cascading dropdown
        cascadingDropDownRelease.resetCascadingDropDowns();
    }
});

$('#container').on('change', function () {
    //this is there I am having the problem.
    var selectedArea = ("#make").val();
    var selectedContainer = $(this).val();

    if (selectedContainer !== "-1") {
        $.post('/Assocation/GetESN',
            { selectedArea: selectedArea, selectedContainer: selectedContainer },
            function (data) {
                cascadingDropDownRelease.resetCascadingDropDowns();
                cascadingDropDownRelease.getESNSuccess(data);
            });
    }
    else {
        cascadingDropDownRelease.resetCascadingDropDowns();
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: `var selectedArea = ("#make").val();` should be `var selectedArea = $("#make").val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var selectedArea = ("#make").val();` should be

```
var selectedArea = $("#make").val();
```

missing the `$`

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't think it would be something quite so embarrassingly small...